# Can't iterate React component to create table. Unexpected token

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs

I'm trying to create a table filled by a REST API using ReactJS. The problem is I don't know what I'm doing wrong with the sintax... I'm using ES6.

This is the FooTable:

```
import React from 'react'
import  Foo from './Foo'

export default class  FooTable extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>surname</td>
    </tr>
    { //<-- This is the marked error by webpack
      this.props. Foos.map( foo=>{
             return  < Foo key={foo.id} name={foo.name} surname={foo.surname}/>
      })
    }
    )
  }//end-render
}
```

This is the Foo class:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return  <tr>
              <td>{foo.name}</td>
              <td>{foo.surname}</td>
            </tr>
  }
}
```

This is the main render:

```
render(){
    if (this.state.foos.length > 0) {
      console.log('Foos size ' + this.state.foos.length);
      return  <table>
                <tbody>
                  <FooTable foos={this.state.foos}/>
                </tbody>
              </table>
   } else {
     return <p className="text-center">Loading Foos...</p>
   }
}
```

Webpack marks an error in FooTable (Unexpected Token). It's marked by a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return single node from your component's (FooTable in this case )render method.

```
render() {
    return(
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>surname</td>
    </tr>
    { //<-- This breaks the single root
      this.props.Foos.map( foo=>{
             return  < Foo key={foo.id} name={foo.name} surname={foo.surname}/>
      })
    }
    )
  }
```

you need to do sth like this :

```
render() {
    return (
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>id</td>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>surname</td>
        </tr>
        {this.props.Foos.map(foo => (<Foo key={foo.id} name={foo.name} surname={foo.surname}/>))}
    </tbody>)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says (see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html#components-are-just-like-functions)) :

> **Note:**
>
> **One limitation:** React components can only render a single root
> node. If you want to return multiple nodes they must be wrapped in a
> single root.

You need to wrap your `<tr>` and your `<Foo>`elements in a single node, for example a `<div>`:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <tr>
       <td>id</td>
       <td>name</td>
       <td>surname</td>
      </tr>
      { //<-- No more multiple roots
        this.props.Foos.map( foo => {
          return  < Foo key={foo.id} name={foo.name} surname={foo.surname}/>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Hope this helps